# Modify Excel file properties

Tags: c#, excel

I have some Excel files on local disk, and I need to access/modify data: right click the Excel file -> Properties -> change the 'comment' under the "details" tab:

[image: Here is the image:]

I simply need to access this attribute and I can also change it using C#.

Is there anyone can help ?

Comment: I found this MSDN article that might help: [How to: Read from and Write to Document Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e0tda25.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to "DSO OLE Document Properties Reader" to your Visual Studio project. (Add References -> COM -> "DSO OLE Document Properties Reader").

Then modify the file properties using the OleDocumentProperties interface like this:

```
var file = new OleDocumentProperties();
file.Open(@"C:\New Folder\Book1.xlsx");
file.SummaryProperties.Comments = "Comment from " + DateTime.UtcNow;
file.Close(true);
```